# Solspace Calendar (2.0.0-b9) returning template not found error in CP

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

In the CraftCMS (3.0.2) control panel > Calendar > Month, when I click on one of my events I get the following error:

```
Template not found: therapy-wellness/_entry
```

I deconstructed the link and found that it's trying to pass the calendar name and the entry URL title to the _entry template. Eg.

```
/calendar-name/my-event-url-title
```

Obviously the issue is that the template to handle this request does not exist, but I'm not clear on when this stopped working or what to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what values you have for the calendar(s) under the Site Settings: **Event URI Format** & **Template**

It's possible you might have something incorrect there. Perhaps the Template path inside the *Event URI Format* area, instead of a proper value like `/calendar_demo/event/{slug}`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your instruction because there doesn't seem to be an "Event URI Format & Template" field within Calendar settings. Can you please be more specific as to where this is located in the Control Panel? I went to Settings > Calendar and looked in "General Settings", "Event Settings", "Guest Access", and "Demo Templates" but there's no field named "Event URI Format & Template" in any of these. Is there mention of this field in your documentation?

Comment: Nvm, I figured out what you're referring to. For each calendar, there are Site Settings accessed by going to Calendar > Calendars > Your Calendar Name > Site Settings

Comment: Still, I'm not really sure what these values (Event URI Format and Template) should be to make the calendar work in the CP. Can you please point me to documentation that explains this?

Comment: This works the same way it does when setting up routes/paths in "sections" for Craft Entries. "Event URI Format" is equivalent to "Entry URI Format", where you're telling Calendar/Craft what the URI should look like for the single event page. The "Template" spot is the template you're using to serve that URI path. It works the same way as it does for native Craft entries, so there's no Calendar-specific documentation for this. :)